# Eclipse 2023-06 suddenly no longer auto completing 'sysout'

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

While I recognize that this problem has been asked before, I have attempted solutions from multiple different threads with no solution as of yet.
5 days ago when I was using Eclipse I had no issues whatsoever, now as of today I suddenly cannot auto complete 'sysout' with 'ctrl + space'.
As far as I am aware, there were no updates to Eclipse.

I have gone through 'Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced' and ensured that nothing was checked that interfered or conflicted with Eclipse being able to auto complete the java command, then reset to defaults.
I checked that 'syso' was a listed and active template.
I made sure that there was not another keybind that was conflicting with 'ctrl + space'
[Window -> ... -> Content Assist -> Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfSb8.png)

[Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BftNz.png)

[General -> Keys(filtered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8OSN.png)

I did discover however that after I close Eclipse, and then open it back up, I can autocomplete 'sysout' once or twice, and then it stops and just pulls up the proposal context menu instead.
The below gif does not show the proposal menu for some reason and I couldn't get it to capture, but it most definitely shows up with 'System.out.println();' as the only option:
[Attempting to use 'sysout' shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGkcb.gif)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://mastodon.social/@howlger/110462282002158739). In _General > Key_ select a command, set the focus into the field _Binding_ and hit Ctrl+Space. If Ctrl+Space is not shown, something is catching the shortcut so Eclipse and other applications do not get Ctrl+Space.

Comment: @howlger Tried that and 'ctrl + space' is showing, so I do not think another application or process is hijacking the keybind

Comment: Please show _General > Keys_ filtered with `Ctrl+Space`. If you switch to a fresh workspace, does the issue persist?

Comment: @howlger I have a photo showing keybinds sorted in order already, but I will add a photo with only 'ctrl + space' singled out. 
And yes, the issue persists across all workspaces, and newly created ones.

Comment: Try restoring the defaults on the 'Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced' page, and if that doesn't fix it, try disabling that non-blocking option at the bottom.

Comment: @nitind Goodness, that solved it. I thought I already tried that >_>
Feel free to post that as the answer

Comment: Which one ended up clearing up the problem, @NathanH?

Comment: @nitind, apologies. I got ahead of myself and didn't clarify. Unchecking 'Enable non-blocking completion' seemed to have worked.

Comment: If you happened to install [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/#:~:text=Microsoft%20PowerToys,-%3A%20Utilities%20to%20customize) and enable the `Peek` functionality. Then change `Peek`'s activation shortcut or disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Always try restoring the defaults on the 'Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced' page, and if that doesn't fix it, try disabling that non-blocking option at the bottom. It's one of the few significant changes to the overall behavior in that area for a while.