# Not getting suggestions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am using eclipse IDE for the coding of my automation test using selenium and java. It used to suggest me the methods and arguments when I use ctrl+space after "." but now it is not giving any suggestions.

Comment: Have you restored the default preference values on the relevant Content Assist preference pages?

Comment: Does [one of the comments or the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76484336/6505250) help?

Comment: @nitind Yes I did restore defaults in preferences > Java > Editor > Content assist but no luck. Also have imported all the classes again in the code but again no luck

Comment: [In my case, it was this](https://mastodon.social/@howlger/110462282002158739). In _General > Keys_ select a command, set the focus into the field _Binding_ and hit Ctrl+Space. If Ctrl+Space is not shown, something is hijacking the shortcut so Eclipse and other applications do not get Ctrl+Space.

Comment: @nitind Thank you. I did restore defaults in content assist > advanced and it worked. I have done restore defaults in content assist and was checking. It was my bad.

Comment: @nitind I'm pretty sure that's a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76484336/6505250) you answered. Maybe it is related/caused by Mylyn being back in combination with an old workspace (@ Dish: with which Eclipse version did you create the workspace you currently use?). Unfortunately, [the question has been reopened by Selenium without comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76520498/revisions). Could you close it again as I'm not allowed to do and the other question provides more details. The number of views on both questions could indicate that it affects a lot users.

Comment: @howlger I use eclipse kepler.  I actually tried to do restore defaults but it was my mistake in performing the action. When I again do the same properly, it worked. I tried to delete this question but as there are comments, I am not able to delete this question or close it. I am sorry.